# Document package in R

Tags: r, package, documentation, roxygen

I've made an R package and want to document it. I've managed to write documentation with roxygen for the functions that's included in my package `easyalgorithms`, but if I type in console:

```
> ?easyalgorithms
No documentation for ‘easyalgorithms’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??easyalgorithms’
```

I've found this guide: https://r-pkgs.org/man.html#man-packages
where it's suggested that you type `packages?foo`. So in my case I tried the following but it's not working:

```
> packages?easyalgorithms
Error in (function (e1, e2)  : 
  no documentation of type ‘packages’ and topic ‘easyalgorithms’ (or error in processing help)
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't quite understand if I'm giving the wrong input or if I'm typing it in the wrong place (right now I'm using the console).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not available by default. The easiest is to use `usethis::use_package_doc()`, see [?usethis::use_package_doc](https://usethis.r-lib.org/reference/use_package_doc.html).

It will create your package help file that you can then edit a your convenience.